# Loop infinito com $_SESSION e redirecionamento

Tags: php, session

Quais seriam as melhores práticas para manobrar o seguinte código PHP?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['senha'], $_SESSION['nivel'], $logado)){
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

E é obvio que quando mato a sessão ele entra em loop infinito pelo simples fato que ela não existe. Mas, como faço para ele parar de loopar?

Quando executo o código aparece a seguinte tela:
[image: Esta página da web tem um loop de redirecionamento]

Comment: Qual o código da index.php, ela tem a mesmo if, se tiver tire só isso resolve ?

Comment: Apesar de você já ter recebido várias respostas, faltou dizer algo que, para fazê-lo preciso saber o que seria a variável **$logado**

Comment: mais uma var para quando o email for verificado ele inicializá-la com o valor 1 caso o processo tenha dado certo

Answer (score 4):

Caso o problema seja um include em todas as páginas, basta adicionar uma ou mais exceções.

Exemplo:

```
if( $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] != '/index.php'
    && !isset($_SESSION['email'], $_SESSION['senha'], $_SESSION['nivel'], $logado)) {

   header("location: index.php");
}
```

<sub>sugestão não relacionada ao problema: sempre use o URL completo no location, se possível.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Você deve ter um conjunto de páginas que requerem que o usuário esteja logado (por exemplo: Ver Perfil, Painel Administrativo, Editar Artigo, etc). Para essas faça seu if e redirecione para uma página login.php.

Mas você deve também ter páginas que não precisam de login para funcionar (por exemplo: Ler Artigo, Fazer Login, Registrar). Para essas faça a condicional apenas para modificar elementos da página. Se é para ler um artigo, cheque se o usuário está logado e coloque o nome dele ali. Caso contrário bote um botão "entrar". Nessas páginas você não vai redirecionar. Isso inclui, obviamente, a página de fazer login.

Comment: No caso a únicas páginas que são acessadas sem que o usuário esteja logado são as paginas de Login. Não estou sabendo como fazer a checagem correta. Na verdade a única coisa que eu quero com essa pergunta é checar se o usuário está logado ou não...

Comment: @Luitame Mas você já tem uma condicional que faz a checagem. Apenas sete uma variável para true quando o usuário estiver logado e use ela para mudar coisas na interface.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecione para a página de autenticação...

Essa parte:

```
header("location: index.php");
```

Troque por:

```
header("location: login.php");
```

*login.php é um exemplo. 
E claro, não coloque a checagem da sessão na página de login senão ficará no mesmo loop.